how to switch the background using css buttons
I have a dark theme and a theme toggle button. I want the image to become darker when clicking on the button from the "light" theme to the "dark" one. How do I do this? Help please.


document.getElementById('hide-checkbox').addEventListener('click', function() {
    const currentTheme = document.body.className;
    if (currentTheme === 'light-theme') {
        document.body.className = 'dark-theme';
        //localStorage.setItem('theme', 'css/Style.css');
    } else {
        document.body.className = 'light-theme';
        //localStorage.setItem('theme', 'css/Style.css');
    }
});
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    background-image: url("https://sun9-66.userapi.com/impg/U_B0e4HYLxsYNJIxFpYW6jR12JhDy76x2zhkXw/O4OafXIrfLc.jpg?size=2560x1920&quality=95&sign=c9143650a2af6853e49e25e18475c8f4&type=album");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
* {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 93%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#hide-checkbox {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

.toggle {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #211042;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transition: 500ms;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.toggle-button {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 7px;
  left: 6px;
  width: 86px;
  height: 86px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #FAEAF1;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 35px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255);
  transition: all 500ms ease-out;
}

.crater {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #FAEAF1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 500ms;
}

.crater-1 {
  background: #FFFFF9;
  width: 86px;
  height: 86px;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.crater-2 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: -7px;
  left: 44px;
}

.crater-3 {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  top: 20px;
  right: -4px;
}

.crater-4 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  top: 24px;
  left: 30px;
}

.crater-5 {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  top: 40px;
  left: 48px;
}

.crater-6 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  top: 48px;
  left: 20px;
}

.crater-7 {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 35px;
}

.star {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 1px 0 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255);
}

.star-1 {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  right: 90px;
  bottom: 40px;
}

.star-2 {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  right: 70px;
  top: 10px;
}

.star-3 {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  right: 60px;
  bottom: 15px;
}

.star-4 {
  width: 3px;
  height: 3px;
  right: 40px;
  bottom: 50px;
}

.star-5 {
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 35px;
}

.star-6, .star-7, .star-8 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  box-shadow: 5px 0px 4px 1px #FFF;
  animation-name: travel;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.star-6 {
  right: 30px;
  bottom: 30px;
  animation-delay: -2s;
}

.star-7 {
  right: 50px;
  bottom: 60px;
}

.star-8 {
  right: 90px;
  top: 10px;
  animation-delay: -4s;
}

@keyframes travel {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(70px);
  }

  50% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(-20px);
    box-shadow: 5px 0px 6px 1px #FFF;
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(-30px);
    width: 2px;
    height: 2px;
    opacity: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}

#hide-checkbox:checked + .toggle {
  background: #24D7F7;
}

#hide-checkbox:checked + .toggle .toggle-button {
  background: #F7FFFF;
  transform: translateX(102px);
  box-shadow: 0 0 35px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255);
}

#hide-checkbox:checked + .toggle .toggle-button .crater {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(70px);
}

#hide-checkbox:checked + .toggle .star {
  animation: move 2s infinite;
  transform: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

#hide-checkbox:checked + .toggle .star-1 {
  width: 40px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #FFF;
  left: 20px;
  top: 25px;
  box-shadow: none;
}

#hide-checkbox:checked + .toggle .star-2 {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: #FFF;
  left: 26px;
  top: 23px;
  box-shadow: -1px 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0 , 0, 0.1);
}

#hide-checkbox:checked + .toggle .star-3 {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background: #FFF;
  left: 35px;
  top: 19px;
  box-shadow: -1px 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0 , 0, 0.1);
}

#hide-checkbox:checked + .toggle .star-4 {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background: #FFF;
  left: 46px;
  top: 21px;
  box-shadow: -1px 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0 , 0, 0.1);
}

#hide-checkbox:checked + .toggle .star-5 {
  width: 60px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: #FFF;
  left: 30px;
  bottom: 20px;
  box-shadow: none;
}

#hide-checkbox:checked + .toggle .star-6 {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 38px;
  bottom: 20px;
  box-shadow: -1px 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0 , 0, 0.1);
}

#hide-checkbox:checked + .toggle .star-7 {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 52px;
  bottom: 20px;
  box-shadow: -1px 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0 , 0, 0.1);
}

#hide-checkbox:checked + .toggle .star-8 {
  width: 21px;
  height: 21px;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 70px;
  top: 59px;
  box-shadow: -1px 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0 , 0, 0.1);
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: none;
  }

  25% {
    transform: translateX(2px);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateX(-2px);
  }
}

body.light-theme {
    background-color: #ffffff;

}

body.dark-theme {
filter: brightness(0.6);
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>{{title}}</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/Style.css') }}">
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="image">
      <input type="checkbox" id="hide-checkbox">
      <label for="hide-checkbox" class="toggle">
        <span class="toggle-button">
          <span class="crater crater-1"></span>
          <span class="crater crater-2"></span>
          <span class="crater crater-3"></span>
          <span class="crater crater-4"></span>
          <span class="crater crater-5"></span>
          <span class="crater crater-6"></span>
          <span class="crater crater-7"></span>
        </span>
        <span class="star star-1"></span>
        <span class="star star-2"></span>
        <span class="star star-3"></span>
        <span class="star star-4"></span>
        <span class="star star-5"></span>
        <span class="star star-6"></span>
        <span class="star star-7"></span>
        <span class="star star-8"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
        </div>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/tema.js') }}"></script>
</html>




Your HTML seems to be missing the <body> tag (and the closing </head> tag)...

the theme does apply, but you css does almost nothing when switching from one to the other (except a filter on brightness, which is visible if you pay attention)

how do I make the image darker???

You could have a second darker image you switch to, put an overlay on it, use some css filter. I'm not 100% sure what the issue you're facing is.

Is it possible to switch the image using a button?

If you want to switch betwen background images with button => where is the second  image ? If not if you are trying to make exiting image darker then specify...

where should I add the second image?

 document.getElementById('hide-checkbox').addEventListener('click', function(){
      const bodyElement = document.body; 
      const currentTheme = bodyElement.className;    
      if (currentTheme === 'light-theme') {
        bodyElement.classList.remove('light-theme');
        bodyElement.classList.add('dark-theme');
      } else {
        bodyElement.classList.remove('dark-theme');
        bodyElement.classList.add('light-theme');
      }
    
      // Save theme preference in local storage (optional)
      // localStorage.setItem('theme', currentTheme); // Uncomment if needed
    });

css here
    body {
          margin: 0;
          font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
          background-position: center center;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-attachment: fixed;
          background-size: cover;
        }
        
        .light-theme {
          background-image: url("https://sun9-66.userapi.com/impg/U_B0e4HYLxsYNJIxFpYW6jR12JhDy76x2zhkXw/O4OafXIrfLc.jpg?size=2560x1920&quality=95&sign=c9143650a2af6853e49e25e18475c8f4&type=album");
         
        }
        
        .dark-theme {
          background-image: url("your_dark_theme_image.jpg"); /* Replace with your dark theme image URL */
          
        }
    ... add remaining css here

remove
body.light-theme {
    background-color: #ffffff;

}

updated html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>{{title}}</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/Style.css') }}">

<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/tema.js') }}"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="image">
      <input type="checkbox" id="hide-checkbox">
      <label for="hide-checkbox" class="toggle">
        <span class="toggle-button">
          <span class="crater crater-1"></span>
          <span class="crater crater-2"></span>
          <span class="crater crater-3"></span>
          <span class="crater crater-4"></span>
          <span class="crater crater-5"></span>
          <span class="crater crater-6"></span>
          <span class="crater crater-7"></span>
        </span>
        <span class="star star-1"></span>
        <span class="star star-2"></span>
        <span class="star star-3"></span>
        <span class="star star-4"></span>
        <span class="star star-5"></span>
        <span class="star star-6"></span>
        <span class="star star-7"></span>
        <span class="star star-8"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>


there is an error in js;(

Just a Parenthesis missing check now

@SoundestMage wereyou able to figure it out ?
